# Grail Using GGTS on ORM / GORM

Tags: database, grails, orm, grails-orm, ggts

I just start using Grails with GGTS (Groovy/Grails Tool Suite) and I trying to test the Object-Relational Mapping on it.

Does anyone know how it works? To write a code and be able to save it in database!?

Could you give me an example on Code? (Doesn't matter if it's simple)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you checking [Grails documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#quickStartGuide), but you can use a simple `dataObj.save()` method or a more complete method in your service, like:

```
class DataTypeService {
    def saveDataObj(DataType dataObj) {
        if(!dataObj.hasErrors() && dataObj.save(failOnError: true)) return dataObj.id

        return false
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
class ExampleController {
    def DataTypeService

    def saving(){
        def dataObj = new DateType(params)
        // ...
        def saved = DataTypeService.saveDataObj(dataObj),

        response = saved ? "object id:${saved} was saved" : 'it fails! try again'

        render response
    }
}
```

You can put it in a try catch or evaluate its response as you want.

Comment: dataObj.save is validating (or checking for errors) as part of the saving process so hence no actual need for !dataObj.hasErrors()

Answer (score 0):

You can find information and tutorials in the official [grails documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#quickStartGuide). Follow the quick start guide to quickly understand how to use GORM.